# Python Tkinter module not showing output

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to learn Python and trying something GUI in Python and came across this Tkinter module. My code runs but the window does not appear when I run. My code is as follows:

```
from Tkinter import *
#to create a root window 
root = Tk()
```

The program runs, gives no errors but the window does not show up.

Comment: Yeah it is workinng now thanks... But where shall I put my buttons and all after root.mainloop()?

Comment: @JoelCornett, you saved my day after 9 years :-D

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add this to your code `root.mainloop()`, [Here's a tutorial](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/firstexample.html).

**In response to your comment**

```
#Also note that `from <module> import *` is generally frowned upon
#since it can lead to namespace collisions. It's much better to only
#explicitly import the things you need.
from Tkinter import Tk, Label
root = Tk()
w = Label(root, text="Hello, world!")
w.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5):

As other answers have pointed out, you need to call `mainloop` on the root object.

I recommend an OO-style of programming, and I also recommend *not* doing a global import (ie: *not* 'from Tkinter import *').

Here's a template I usually start out with:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class ExampleView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        l = tk.Label(self, text="your widgets go here...", anchor="c")
        l.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

if __name__=='__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    view = ExampleView(root)
    view.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

This makes it easy to keep your main logic at the start of the file, and keep the creation of the root and the calling of `mainloop` together, which I think makes the code a little bit easier to understand. It also makes reusing this code a little easier (ie: you could create a larger program where this is one of several windows that can be created)

Answer (score 2):

Add `root.mainloop()` at the end.