# tkinter not recognised under python 3.7

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using Python 3.7, and as far as I know it already comes itself with tkinter.

The line `import tkinter as tk` causes in my IntelliJ IDEA the warning:

"Python version 2.7 does not have module tkinter"

Under |Preferences -> Project:'project name' -> Project Interpreter|, is clearly the 3.7 version choosen.

In practice, this code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("mein GUI")

root.resizable(False, False)
w = 500  # width for the Tk root
h = 500  # height for the Tk root

sw = root.winfo_screenwidth()
sh = root.winfo_screenheight()

x = (sw / 2) - (w / 2)
y = (sh / 2) - (h / 2)

root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
print("test")
```

runs, prints "test" and don't throws an exception, but no window appears.

---

Im also well aware that `Tkinter` is used for Python versions under 3.0 and `tkinter` for versions equal or above 3.0

Comment: What's the problem? Your code runs fine but doesn't show the window because you didn't write code to show it. If your IDE shows this warning but can run the code anyways, the linter may be misconfigured

Comment: See [Python Tkinter module not showing output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060263/python-tkinter-module-not-showing-output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("mein GUI")

root.resizable(False, False)
w = 500  # width for the Tk root
h = 500  # height for the Tk root

sw = root.winfo_screenwidth()
sh = root.winfo_screenheight()

x = (sw / 2) - (w / 2)
y = (sh / 2) - (h / 2)

root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
print("test")
root.mainloop()
```

Add root.mainloop() to the end of your code and your window will appear

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `root.mainloop()` at the end of your code to show the window. This may be an indirect duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060263/python-tkinter-module-not-showing-output), however in your case your code just needs that at the end and it worked for me.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("mein GUI")

root.resizable(False, False)
w = 500  # width for the Tk root
h = 500  # height for the Tk root

sw = root.winfo_screenwidth()
sh = root.winfo_screenheight()

x = (sw / 2) - (w / 2)
y = (sh / 2) - (h / 2)

root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
print("test")
root.mainloop()
```